# In-class non-static member initialization in class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

This code:

```
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A(string b)
    {
        cout << "A constructed: " << b << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct B
{
    A a{"Text"};
};

int main()
{
    B<int> b;
}
```

will throw this error:
`error: no matching function for call to 'A::A(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'`, I don't understand why this code doesn't compile, but what is more consufing is that when I:

- Make `B` regular (non-template) class OR
- Initialize member `a` in initializer list (instead at point of delcaration) OR
- change `A`'s constructor to take `const char*` instead of `string` OR
- Change `A a{"Test"}` to `A a = "Test"`(copy constructor)

it works? Why is it so?

Compiled using (`g++ 4.8.1`, with `std=c++11` flag)

Comment: On Visual Studio 2015 your example works as expected. So it is g++ specific thing. Maybe wrong templates processing.

Comment: This is bug [#58753](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58753) and has been fixed since 4.9.1